# Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root

Tags: macos, usb, mount, sd-card, root

When I plug in my usb memory card reader nothing happens. It was working ten minutes ago when I used the xbian installer to put it on the sd card, but now nada.  Something briefly flashes up then disappears in Disk Utility.  I see this in the system.log

```
Mar 26 17:22:52 Johns-iMac kernel[0]: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 000000009744 0x5e3 0x716 0x9744, 2
Mar 26 17:22:53 Johns-iMac.local com.apple.kextd[19]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
Mar 26 17:22:53 Johns-iMac.local com.apple.kextd[19]: IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport.kext has no Info.plist file.
Mar 26 17:22:53 Johns-iMac.local com.apple.kextd[19]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
Mar 26 17:22:54 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Mar 26 17:22:54 Johns-iMac kernel[0]: disk4s1: I/O error.
Mar 26 17:22:55 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Mar 26 17:22:55 Johns-iMac kernel[0]: disk4s1: media is not present.
Mar 26 17:22:55 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Mar 26 17:22:55 Johns-iMac.local diskarbitrationd[38]: unable to mount /dev/disk4s1 (status code 0x00000047).
```

The owner/group of the root folder is my user account and `staff`

```
Johns-iMac:~ john$ ls -al /
total 93
drwxrwxrwx   34 john  staff   1224 26 Mar 17:04 .
drwxrwxrwx   34 john  staff   1224 26 Mar 17:04 ..
-rw-rw-r--@   1 root  admin   8196  5 Mar 19:38 .DS_Store
```

Who should own the root folder? root or me?

The real problem is that the system can't read my memory card.  How to fix?

Comment: The root folder should be owned by the system (root). Probably some subsequent folders are also owned by you instead of root. Boot to Recovery HD and fix it with Disk Utility. Please add the SD-card brand/model.

Comment: @klanomath Thanks for your interest.  I think maybe it's actually complaining about who owns the root directly of the mounted drive.  Have discovered other SD drives are fine.  I don't think the card is borked (at least not yet) but rather the filesystem on it is.  So if I can work out some way to mount it without it trying to mount it...?!

Comment: samsung 32gb and some microscopic writing that does not indicate the model

Comment: Please leave a comment when downvoting so that I understand what it is about my question that requires improvement.

Comment: @JohnMee I didn't downvote your question! Instead I starred it. AFAIR I never downvoted a question I commented somehow constructivly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*An hour later...*

Well that's interesting: if I stick it into a different device (a little usb camera) and plug that in, it complains a bit, then mounts!?

```
Mar 26 18:37:34 Johns-iMac.local com.apple.kextd[19]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
Mar 26 18:37:34 Johns-iMac.local com.apple.kextd[19]: IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport.kext has no Info.plist file.
Mar 26 18:37:34 Johns-iMac.local com.apple.kextd[19]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
Mar 26 18:37:34 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Mar 26 18:37:34 Johns-iMac kernel[0]: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 966110000000100 0x603 0x1001 0x100, 2
Mar 26 18:37:36 Johns-iMac.local com.apple.kextd[19]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
Mar 26 18:37:36 Johns-iMac.local com.apple.kextd[19]: IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport.kext has no Info.plist file.
Mar 26 18:37:36 Johns-iMac.local com.apple.kextd[19]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
Mar 26 18:37:36 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Mar 26 18:37:36 Johns-iMac.local fseventsd[20]: check_vol_last_mod_time:XXX failed to get mount time (25; &mount_time == 0x101eff498)
Mar 26 18:37:36 Johns-iMac.local fseventsd[20]: log dir: /Volumes/xbianboot/.fseventsd getting new uuid: 4898DEB3-E8EE-4FB0-BD08-EBECC37F3872
Mar 26 18:37:36 Johns-iMac.local mds[32]: (Volume.Normal:2464) volume:0x7f9020906800 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:1 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:(null) occlude:0 /Volumes/xbianboot
```

From there `Disk Utility` is able to see it and I can `Erase` the contents and start over.

Came down to not using the usb multi card reader thingy.